# AMPL syntax error: "____ is not a set" & "____ is not a param <or constraint or var>"

Tags: syntax, ampl

I'm SUPER new to AMPL programming although experienced with other programming languages.
I have this as the first .dat file my .run is listing:

```
data;

#set declarations
    set TIME = {0..1680} ordered; #time
#   set GENHRS := {150..1660} ; #generation hours

#Scalars
    param StorageMin :=1;#       Minimum reservoir storage level
    param StorageMax :=50;#       Maximum reservoir storage level
    param Qmin       :=1;#       Minimum total outflow 
    param QturbMax   :=20;#       Maximum level of outflow through turbine
    #param Qin {t in TIME};#        need to read in from file.
```

as in the title, I'm getting errors running it (through cmd)
"TIME is not a set" and also for ALL other params listed in the above: "___ is not a param ".

I'm very confused. As far as I can tell they are all defined with the correct syntax although I can't figure out the different between ":=" and "=" however I have tried both and neither works..

I have no idea if it is relevant, but constraints, variable and objectives are specified in my .mod file.

Answer (score 0):

The AMPL language consists of two parts or *modes*, a modeling language for specifying an optimization model and a [data specification language](http://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/12-data) for providing set and parameter data. The `data` statement switches AMPL to the data mode where it interprets the input as written in the data specification language.

The AMPL code

```
set TIME = {0..1680} ordered;
```

gives a declaration of set `TIME`, so it should be used in model, not in data.

Answer (score 0):

As vitaut said, the *modes* matter. Meaning that if your setup is a data file, model file and run file where you call `model` and `data`, **you need to call `model` before `data`** in the run file.